# Suggestions on types of models for broad-category text classification

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm quite new to machine learning and am searching for what models would be good to explore on a passion project to help a friend's website out.

The project is essentially that we have a database of documents (some the size of articles, others are short blurbs), and an interface where users can classify these documents by interest categories. These categories vary from things such as (action, sci-fi) to (informative, funny) and can even be as obscure as ('news articles that are funny', or 'articles that contain the word politics'). Once a new category has been created, we want to be able to recognize if other documents fall into this category. However, a document may not fall into any category at all, or could relate to multiple categories. This has become quite a difficult problem to approach. My initial thought is to start with a semantic similarity model, and fine-tune the model whenever a new category is added (obviously there will need to be some training data, i.e. a category and a few documents that are related). Though, if no fine-tuning is needed that would be the best case scenario (not sure that this is logically possible though).

The input of the model should be a new document, and the output should be which existing categories it relates to.

Any ideas on where to begin or what models to look at would be highly appreciated!